# Crystal Report Error. The report has no tables

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I am using blank crystal report and binding my dataset. it shows report has no tables error.

```
 string strSQL = "Select * from EMP"; //WHERE EMPNO='" + txtEmpId.Text + "'
 OracleDataAdapter dt = new OracleDataAdapter(strSQL, scon);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 dt.Fill(ds, "EMP");

 ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
 cryRpt.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/DailyReport.rpt");
 cryRpt.SetDataSource(dt);

 CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
 scon.Close();
```

Comment: What is the exact error? Are you sure your table name is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code

```
 string strSQL = "Select * from EMP"; //WHERE EMPNO='" + txtEmpId.Text + "'
 OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(strSQL, scon);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 DataTable dt = new DataTable("DT_CR");
 da.Fill(dt);
 ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);
 ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
 cryRpt.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/DailyReport.rpt");
 cryRpt.SetDataSource(ds);
 CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
 scon.Close();
```

Comment: It shows error: Cannot find table 0. in line   ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);